# Is it legal in New York to deduct a full-day of PTO during a company-wide early dismissal?

Tags: labor-law, workplace

I took a vacation this past week while my company held a picnic on Friday and dismissed everybody early at 3pm. I asked if I could have the two hours back (or get paid for them) since everybody else was dismissed early. I was told that since I took off, it was considered a full PTO day and that early dismissal was a benefit of having attended the picnic.

The policy was as follows:

- Those who attended the picnic were paid for the full working day
- Those who did not attend (but showed up to work) were clocked out at 12pm (picnic started at 12 and it was business as usual during the morning).
- Employees who did not clock out were automatically clocked out at 12pm.

The policy regarding PTO was not mentioned in the email, which is why I asked.

This is for a company located on Long Island New York in Suffolk County.

Comment: I can't help but feel if you like your job you won't pursue this. Is two hours of wage really worth souring things between yourself and employer, and possibly losing your job and benefits? I guess it is like they say, you should pick and choose your battles. This one does not seem like a good choice of battlefields.

Comment: @jww perhaps, but A) I don't like my job and B) I'm just curious if anything.